Kubuntu default cursor size does not works during boot
In Kubuntu 22.04, I have cursor icon set called Volantes Cursors I succeeded to make it system's default cursor. i.e. it rendered before login in the SDDM. However, during login, I noticed for a while, it becomes smaller in size. The default size, I have chosen 32 px, for it.
The /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme settings are below:
[Icon Theme]
Name=Volantes Cursors
Comment=design by varlesh
Inherits=volantes_cursors
Size=32
MinSize=32
DialogDefault=32
DesktopDefault=32
ToolbarDefault=32

What is the missing of these configurations that makes it rendered in size less than 32 px?
